# update the selected row in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to  update the selected row in the page. I have a webpage where user as to enter the id. In the second page the all the rows and values with the same Id entered as to be displayed for editing. How can i do this..

Here is the code

```
    <form method="post" action="edituser.php">
    <label type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" size="30" class="label">Enter the Membership Number</label><br />
    <input type="text" name='id' placeholder="enter Membership Number" class="input" size="40"/><br />
    <span class="field">(* Required field)</span><br /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="button"><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("anthonys");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $id= $_POST['id'];

    if( ! ctype_alnum($id) )
      die('invalid id');


    $query = "SELECT id FROM `member` WHERE `id` =$id";


    $run = mysql_query($query);


    if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){
    echo "<script>window.open('edit.php?id=".$id."','_self')</script>";
    }

    else {

        echo "<script>alert('Membership No is Invalid!')</script>";
        }
    }
    ?>





    <

h2>Application for the Membership</h2><br /><br />
<table border="0px" style="border-collapse:collapse; width:810px;" align="center">
<tr>
<td>
<form name="XIForm" id="XIForm" method="POST" action="pdf/pdf2.php">
<label type="text" name="uid" maxlength="50" size="30" class="label">Membership No</label><br />
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) { echo $_GET['id']; } ?>" readonly> <br /><br />
<label type="text" name="fathername"  maxlength="50" size="30" class="label">Father`s Name</label><br />
<input  name="fathername"name="fathername" placeholder="" class="input" size="40"value="<?php if(isset($_GET['fathername'])) { echo $_GET['fathername']; } ?>"> <br /><br />









    <input type="hidden" name="formType" id="formType" value="reg"/>
        <input type="button" name="XISubmit" id="XISubmit" value="ADD" class="button" />        


<br /><br /><br /><br />
</form></td>


</tr>
</table>



</div>


</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>

    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("anthonys");

    if(isset($_POST['update'])){



    $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE member SET fathername='$_POST[fathername]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'";               
    $run=mysql_query($UpdateQuery);
    };


    echo "<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th>Fathers_Name</th>
    "</tr>";
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
    echo "<form action=edit.php method=post>";
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=Father_name value=" . $record['fathername'] . " </td>";


    echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['id'] . " </td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
    }
    echo "<form action=edit.php method=post>";
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td><input type=text name=fathername></td>";


    echo "</form>";
    echo "</table>";

    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why are you using the old `mysql_*` functions, and not PDO?

Comment: First correct your mysql connection code..

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a lot of quotes in your strings, you can use `\"` to echo a double quote without closing the string eg:

```
echo "<form action=\"modify.php\" method=\"post\">";
```

Also you shouldn't use unquoted array indexes, while technically this will work,

```
"SET fathername='$_POST[fathername]'"
```

its relying on the fact that php will fall back to a string if it can't locate the constant and will produce warnings:

Instead concatenate it like this:

```
"SET fathername=".$_POST['fathername']."...."
```

you may have some sql injection vulnerabilities in your code, you should read up on that. and use `mysqli_*` not `mysql_*`  as it's depreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are getting only id now

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE `id` =$id"; // will give you all the rows
```